# Equality and in-equality operators used in binary search implemented in Java

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, binary-search

I have been trying to figure out why in the binary search code of Java, we have used '<=' rather than simply using a '=='. Is it some sort of optimization?

The following piece of code is from Class: **java.util.Arrays**, method: **binarySearch0()**

Code:

```java
    private static int binarySearch0(long[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, long key) {
        int low = fromIndex;
        int high = toIndex - 1;

        while(low <= high) {
            int mid = low + high >>> 1;
            long midVal = a[mid];
            if (midVal < key) {
                low = mid + 1;
            } else {
                if (midVal <= key) { // Why here have we used '<=' rather than '=='
                    return mid;
                }

                high = mid - 1;
            }
        }

        return -(low + 1);
    }
```

Comment: Which version of Java are you talking about? The sources of 
 Java 8 (http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/be44bff34df4/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#l1825), Java 11 (http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#l1828) and Java 14 (http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk14/file/6c954123ee8d/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#l1619) all look the same and very different from your fragment.

Comment: 1.7 also looks different

Comment: I have been using 11, but now got to know that the decompiler's code is different than the one actually present in the library, Thank you so much guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code differs from the one used within the JDK (http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/be44bff34df4/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#l1825), so I can only assume that you used some kind of decompiler to arrive at your source code.

The original source code is readable and clearly communicates the intention:

```
private static int binarySearch0(long[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex,
                                 long key) {
    int low = fromIndex;
    int high = toIndex - 1;

    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
        long midVal = a[mid];

        if (midVal < key)
            low = mid + 1;
        else if (midVal > key)
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            return mid; // key found
    }
    return -(low + 1);  // key not found.
}
```

Now if you look at the `if` statements:

```
        if (midVal < key)
            low = mid + 1;
        else if (midVal > key)
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            return mid; // key found
```

you could rewrite it as (still the same code as before):

```
        if (midVal < key) {
            low = mid + 1;
        } else  {
            if (midVal > key)
                high = mid - 1;
            else
               return mid; // key found
        }
```

Now you can change the comparison in the second `if` and swap the `then` and `else` branches of that statement:

```
        if (midVal < key) {
            low = mid + 1;
        } else  {
            if (midVal <= key) {
                return mid; // key found
            }
            high = mid - 1;
        }
```

This code is functionally equivalent but the intention is no longer visible.

Comment: Understood about this concept of decompilers outputting the same logic but might not have the same intention shown. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use '==' too. As if midVal < key, it will never go to the else part.

Comment: Yes! exactly, I was just concerned about the preference.